# Python: how to retrieve Google Scholar citations per year?

Tags: python, parsing

I ma trying to retrieve the information from a Google Scholar profile. I have the `url`

```
from bs4 import SoupStrainer, BeautifulSoup
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen

url = "https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=qc6CJjYAAAAJ"
page = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
```

I am able to get information like `h_index`, `i10_index` and `citations` in the following way:

```
indexes = soup.find_all("td", "gsc_rsb_std")
h_index = indexes[2].string
i10_index = indexes[4].string
citations = indexes[0].string
```

Now I would like to know how to get the sum of the citations per year as shown in the Google Scholar graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `re.compile` to find the three classes of table data, including the year citation:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import urllib
import re
s = soup(str(urllib.urlopen('https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=qc6CJjYAAAAJ').read()), 'lxml')
final_data = [[b.text for b in i] for i in s.find_all('td', {'class':re.compile('gsc_a_t|gsc_a_c|gsc_a_y')})]
grouped_data = [final_data[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(final_data), 3)]
citations = [dict(zip(['title', 'cited by', 'year'], map(lambda x:x[0], i))) for i in grouped_data]
```

Output:

```
[{'year': u'1935', 'cited by': u'16471', 'title': u'Can quantum-mechanical description of physical reality be considered complete?'}, {'year': u'1905', 'cited by': u'10925', 'title': u'Uber einen die Erzeugung und Verwandlung des Lichtes betreffenden heurischen Gesichtpunkt'}, {'year': u'1905', 'cited by': u'9425', 'title': u'On the movement of small particles suspended in stationary liquids required by the molecular-kinetic theory of heat'}, {'year': u'1956', 'cited by': u'4648', 'title': u'Investigations on the Theory of the Brownian Movement'}, {'year': u'', 'cited by': u'4540', 'title': u'Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K\xf6rper'}, {'year': u'1911', 'cited by': u'4285', 'title': u'Graviton Mass and Inertia Mass'}, {'year': u'1918', 'cited by': u'4196', 'title': u'On gravitational waves Sitzungsber. preuss'}, {'year': u'1925', 'cited by': u'3947', 'title': u'Sitzungsber. K'}, {'year': u'1917', 'cited by': u'3914', 'title': u'Sitzungsberichte der Preussischen Akad. d'}, {'year': u'1906', 'cited by': u'3633', 'title': u'Eine neue bestimmung der molek\xfcldimensionen'}, {'year': u'1950', 'cited by': u'3538', 'title': u'The meaning of relativity'}, {'year': u'1998', 'cited by': u'3472', 'title': u'Ueber einen die Erzeugung und Verwandlung des Lichtes betreffenden heuristischen Gesichtspunkt'}, {'year': u'1915', 'cited by': u'3065', 'title': u'Sitzungsberichte der Preussischen Akademie der Wissenschaften zu Berlin'}, {'year': u'1954', 'cited by': u'2969', 'title': u'Evolution of Physics'}, {'year': u'1920', 'cited by': u'2919', 'title': u'The special and general theory'}, {'year': u'2006', 'cited by': u'2804', 'title': u'Die grundlage der allgemeinen relativit\xe4tstheorie'}, {'year': u'1982', 'cited by': u'2643', 'title': u'The Science and the Life of Albert Einstein'}, {'year': u'1917', 'cited by': u'2570', 'title': u'Zur quantentheorie der strahlung'}, {'year': u'1954', 'cited by': u'2489', 'title': u'Physics and Reality, in \u201cIdeas and Opinions\u201d'}, {'year': u'1924', 'cited by': u'2440', 'title': u'Quantum theory of monatomic ideal gases'}]
```

Edit: to find the values in the graph, slightly alter the data passed to `find_all`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import urllib
import re
s = soup(str(urllib.urlopen('https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=qc6CJjYAAAAJ').read()), 'lxml')
years = map(int, [i.text for i in s.find_all('span', {'class':'gsc_g_t'})])
citation_number = map(int, [i.text for i in s.find_all('span', {'class':'gsc_g_al'})])
final_chart_data = dict(zip(years, citation_number))
```

Output:

```
{1979: 774, 1980: 649, 1981: 572, 1982: 722, 1983: 680, 1984: 725, 1985: 743, 1986: 664, 1987: 776, 1988: 792, 1989: 879, 1990: 924, 1991: 831, 1992: 1071, 1993: 1016, 1994: 1197, 1995: 1300, 1996: 1283, 1997: 1409, 1998: 1433, 1999: 1777, 2000: 1987, 2001: 2300, 2002: 2347, 2003: 2449, 2004: 2927, 2005: 4436, 2006: 4059, 2007: 4476, 2008: 4409, 2009: 4709, 2010: 4586, 2011: 5139, 2012: 5797, 2013: 6160, 2014: 5985, 2015: 6463, 2016: 6760, 2017: 6356, 2018: 396}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I would need the information of the graph on the right. The sum of citations per year

Comment: But this considers only the first 20 papers, how to handle when the author has more than 20 papers. That is the Google Scholar profile lists only 20 papers, hence the URL reads only these 20 papers when there could be more, which is usually shown by using the 'SHOW MORE' button.

Answer (score 1):

Also you could use scholarly:

```
import scholarly
author_name="..."
author = next(scholarly.search_author(author_name)).fill()
pubs = author.publications
```

Also, for more advanced visualisation and text analytics on scholar output you can check my lib that uses scholarly: https://github.com/tyiannak/pyScholar

Answer (score 0):

You could use a third party solution like SerpApi to scrape the graph on the right side of the user profile. It's a paid API with a free trial.

Example python code (available in other libraries also):

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
  "api_key": "SECRET_API_KEY",
  "engine": "google_scholar_author",
  "author_id": "qc6CJjYAAAAJ",
  "hl": "en"
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()
```

Example JSON output:

```json
"cited_by": {
  "table": [
    {
      "citations": {
        "all": 139782,
        "since_2016": 37906
      }
    },
    {
      "h_index": {
        "all": 119,
        "since_2016": 66
      }
    },
    {
      "i10_index": {
        "all": 394,
        "since_2016": 219
      }
    }
  ],
  "graph": [
    {
      "year": 1982,
      "citations": 614
    },
    {
      "year": 1983,
      "citations": 680
    },
    {
      "year": 1984,
      "citations": 736
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

You can check out the [documentation](https://serpapi.com/google-scholar-author-cited-by) for more details.

Disclaimer: I work at SerpApi.