# How to scroll slider in Google scholar using selenium webdriver

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to scroll the slider (marked in red in below screenshot) towards right in the Google Scholar Page using selenium web driver, but without success

[image: Scroll]

I'm currently trying to do using the Action Chains in the below code, but without luck !

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

#Loading the Chromium web driver manager and assigning to a variable 'browser'
browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
browser.get('https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=dqwjm-0AAAAJ&hl=en&oi=ao')

#Maximize the browser window
browser.maximize_window()

#Clicking on the find button
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='gsc_hist_opn']/span/span").click()
time.sleep(5)

#Code to select the slider

slider = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="gsc_md_hist_c"]/div/div[3]')
time.sleep(5)
ActionChains(browser).click_and_hold(slider).move_by_offset(-100, 0).release().perform()
```

Can somebody tell how the slider in the screenshot could be moved towards right using the Selenium Web driver?

EDIT : The link which I'm trying is [present here](https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=kukA0LcAAAAJ&hl=en&oi=ao).From the main page we find hyper link `view all` for citations (upper right).On clicking that hyper link we get the chart (Citations per year) as mentioned in screenshot

Comment: Similar stack overflow post answers this question :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48503665/python-how-to-retrieve-google-scholar-citations-per-year/48503895

Answer (score 0):

See the [following](https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/handle-scroll-bar-in-selenium/) tutorial.
There are several additional tutorials as well.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer.I had a look at the link which you posted.It works when there is HTML code written for scroll.However in my case when I click on inspect element for that part there is no HTML code for scroll written.How can I proceed in such circumstances ?

Comment: What do you mean by `no HTML code for scroll written`? Every webpage is built on/by HTML code.

Comment: yeah, agree. But in my case (as in screenshot) that horizontal scroll slider is automatically generated when the content is too big to fit in an area.Even the slider(dark grey) in my question (the code part) is generated due to the content being too large to fit.It is called overflow in html. Apologies for any confusion.

Comment: OK, but I still see no difference. Once the content is big and slider appears it should be an element that you can locate and use.

Comment: Yup, But I'm unable to locate that element in which slider belongs to.In my code (pasted) I tried finding via xpath but without success.I also tried to find the slider(dark grey slider) in this page using inspect element but no luck.I'm able to view the class but not element for slider.

Comment: We could help you if you provide the link to that webpage, but you didn't...

Comment: Thanks, I edited my post.The link is present in the post now

Comment: Hm. I can't catch that element too. But you can try workaround: there are 15 spans and 15 hrefs there. So you can scroll into view last or first href or span element there. Tell me if this worked.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work, what I tried was to scroll the first href element which resulted in element not interactable exception

Comment: Currently I have no idea, I'm sorry. Please let me know if you finally find the solution. It's interesting.

Comment: The similar Stack Overflow post answers this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48503665/python-how-to-retrieve-google-scholar-citations-per-year/48503895